# Laplace Question $f(t) = e^{-t} \sin(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, laplace-method, laplace-expansion

I need help with this Laplace question.
$$f(t) = e^{-t} \sin(t) $$

---

Answer should be $\dfrac{1}{s^2 + 2s + 2}$

---

What I'm currently doing is as follows:

$u = \sin(t)\qquad$       $dv = e^{-(s+1)t}dt$

$du = \cos(t)dt\qquad$    $v = \dfrac{e^{-(s+1)t}}{-(s+1)}$

$\dfrac{-\sin(t) e^{-(s+1)t}}{-(s+1)}  - \int\dfrac{ e^{-(s+1)t}\cos(t)}{ -(s+1)} dt$

But even if I solved the integral, I wouldn't get this (which is what I should, see picture).

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for the table, but I can't just plug in an already built equation. I sadly need to elaborate everything (integration by parts).

Comment: Are you permitted to use any of the common Laplace transforms or must you use only the integral definition $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)\,dt$?

Comment: from the integral definition to calculate the transform of Laplace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not integrate by parts to evaluate this integral.  In fact, one would need to integrate by parts twice.  **See the section following the highlighted SPOILER ALERT**

So, I thought it would be instructive to present a "trick" that we can use to quickly evaluate the integral of interest and other similar integrals.

**HERE IS A HINT:**

$$\sin(t)=\text{Im}\left(e^{it}\right) \tag 1$$

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Using $(1)$, we have$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sin(t)e^{-st}\,dt&=\text{Im}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{(-1-s+i)t}\,dt\right)\\\\&=\text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{-(1+s)+i)}\right)\\\\&=\text{Im}\left(\frac{-(s+1)-i}{(s+1)^2+1}\,dt\right)\\\\&=\frac{1}{s^2+2s+2}\end{align}$$as was to be shown!  Quick, painless, and less prone to careless errors.

---

The last result in the OP was

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sin(t)e^{-st}\,dt=\left.\left(\frac{-\sin(t) e^{-(s+1)t}}{-(s+1)}\right)\right|_0^\infty  - \int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{ e^{-(s+1)t}\cos(t)}{ -(s+1)} dt$$

Continuing we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sin(t)e^{-st}\,dt&=\frac{1}{s+1} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(s+1)t}\cos(t)\,dt \tag 2
\end{align}$$

We integrate by parts $(2)$ with $u=\cos(t)$ and $v=-\frac{e^{-(s+1)t}}{s+1}$.  Then, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sin(t)e^{-st}\,dt&=\frac{1}{s+1}\left.\left(-\frac{\cos(t)e^{-(s+1)t}}{s+1}\right)\right|_0^\infty -\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}\int_0^\infty \sin(t)e^{-(s+1)t}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}\int_0^\infty \sin(t)e^{-(s+1)t}\,dt\\\\
((s+1)^2+1)\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sin(t)e^{-st}\,dt&=1\\\\
\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sin(t)e^{-st}\,dt&=\frac{1}{s^2+2s+2}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand how this trick is applied. Looks like very advanced math. I'm still cursing first year of college.

Comment: Have you learned Euler's Formula $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$.  If not, that's OK.  Let's use this identity.  In the highlighted area, you will see the integration carried out in the exact same way the integral of an exponential is carried out.  Then, to take the imaginary part, simply multiply the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @RicardoCastillo I edited to add a way forward with integration by parts.  - Mark

Comment: Thank you for the best vote!!  Much appreciative.  - Mark

Comment: Thank you Dr. MV. This was a tricky one for me! Good thing there lot's of smart people out there like yourself willing to help

Comment: @RicardoCastillo Ricardo, you're welcome!  My pleasure. And thank you for the nice words. - Mark

Answer (score 1):

Here's the 'direct' proof:
$f(t)=e^{-t}\sin t.$
\begin{eqnarray*}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(s+1)t}\sin t\,dt~=~\lim_{\ell\to+\infty}\int_{0}^{\ell}e^{-(s+1)t}\sin t\,dt\\
   &=&-\frac{1}{s+1}\lim_{\ell\to+\infty}\left[e^{-(s+1)t}\sin t\Big|_{0}^{\ell}-\int_{0}^{\ell}e^{-(s+1)t}\cos t\,dt\right]\\
   &=&\frac{1}{s+1}\lim_{\ell\to+\infty}\int_{0}^{\ell}e^{-(s+1)t}\cos t\,dt,
 \end{eqnarray*}
since $$\lim_{\ell\to+\infty}e^{-(s+1)\ell}\sin\ell=0.$$ Integrating again by parts yields
\begin{eqnarray*}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}&=&-\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}\lim_{\ell\to+\infty}\left[e^{-(s+1)t}\cos t\Big|_{0}^{\ell}+\int_{0}^{\ell}e^{-(s+1)t}\sin t\,dt\right]\\
  &=&\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}\left[1-\lim_{\ell\to+\infty}\int_{0}^{\ell}e^{-(s+1)t}\sin t\,dt\right]\\
  &=&\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}(1-\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\})
 \end{eqnarray*}
and finally solving by $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$,
$$\boxed{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}=\frac{1}{s^2+2s+2}}~.$$

Answer (score 0):

Calculate Laplace transform for $f(t)$ and $e^{-t}\cos(t)$ then you'll get a equation system where the unknowns will be the integrals 
$$\int\dfrac{ e^{-(s+1)t}\cos(t)}{ -(s+1)} dt \text{ and } \int\dfrac{ e^{-(s+1)t}\sin(t)}{ -(s+1)} dt $$
with this you can conclude.