# How to solve this laplace transforms?

Tags: laplace-transform

Find the Laplace of the given function using the definition

$f(t)=e^{-t} \operatorname{sen}(t)$

I know what the answer is according to a sheet that I have of common transforms but I am not 100% on how to get there using the definition

I don't know how to get out of this infinite integration of sin(t) and cos(t)

---

what I've been trying:

$\begin{aligned}
& \text { g) } f(t)=e^{-t} \operatorname{sen}(t) \\
& \mathcal{L }\left\{e^{-t} \operatorname{sen}(t)\right\}=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-s t} \cdot e^{-t} \operatorname{sen}(t) d t=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t(s+1)} \operatorname{sen}(t)dt \\
\end{aligned}$

$\begin{aligned}
& \left.\left(-\frac{\operatorname{sen}(t)}{s+1}\right) e^{-t(s+1)}\right)_0^{\infty}+\frac{1}{s+1} \int e^{-t(s+1)} \cos (t) dt \\
& \frac{1}{s+1}\left[-\frac{\cos (t)}{s+1} e^{-t(s+1)}-\frac{1}{s+1} \int e^{-t(s+1)} \operatorname{sen}(t) d t\right]
\end{aligned}$

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laplace Question $f(t) = e^{-t} \sin(t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689523/laplace-question-ft-e-t-sint)

Comment: I just have a question on this part: $\begin{aligned}
\left((s+1)^2+1\right) & \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} \sin (t) e^{-s t} d t=1 \\
& \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} \sin (t) e^{-s t} d t=\frac{1}{s^2+2 s+2}
\end{aligned}$  I mean, basically it's like: "Then you're done there, but it's like this: L{f(t)} = ...."